# How do I display the results of an aggregate SOQL query on a Visualforce page?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, soql

I'm very new to Visualforce.

I'm looking at this page here: http://force.siddheshkabe.co.in/2010/11/displaying-aggregate-result-on.html

So when I added this code onto a VisualForce page:

```
  AggregateResult[] groupedResults  = [SELECT Name, Days__c FROM Contact WHERE Days__c != ];

  for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {
    System.debug('Name: ' + ar.get('Name') + '\nDays Taken : ' + ar.get('Days__c') + '\n');
```

But all it does is print the code instead of executing it. What should I be doing? Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Apex code goes into a [custom controller or controller extension](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_controller.htm). The VisualForce page is a separate file from the controller. The page you referenced doesn't show the VF page. Also, I don't think you can bind VF components to `AggregateResult`, so you'll need a wrapper class.

Here's some working code.

Controller:

```
public with sharing class TestController {

    public Summary[] Summaries { get; set; }

    public TestController() {
        AggregateResult[] results = [
            SELECT Name, Count(Id) Quantity FROM Opportunity GROUP BY Name
        ];
        Summaries = new List<Summary>();
        for (AggregateResult ar : results) {
            Summaries.add(new Summary(ar));
        }
    }

    // wrapper class to hold aggregate data
    public class Summary {
        public Integer Quantity { get; private set; }
        public String Name { get; private set; }

        public Summary(AggregateResult ar) {
            Quantity = (Integer) ar.get('Quantity');
            Name = (String) ar.get('Name');
        }
    }

}
```

VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="TestController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:repeat value="{!Summaries}" var="summary">
            {!summary.Name}: {!summary.Quantity}<br/>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I'm getting an "illegal assignment from LIST<Opportunity> to List<AggregateResult>". I tried changing AggregateResult[] results to LIST<AggregateResult> results but same deal. Any ideas?

Comment: That means your SOQL query has no aggregate functions, so a plain ol' List of Opportunity is being returned.